# Testing amazon SWF workflow

Tags: unit-testing, amazon-swf

I am trying to write tests for my SWF workflow, but stuck with a problem, which I am guessing is because of the asynchronous code or Settable objects in my workflow.

My code looks like

```
@Asynchronous public Promise doSomething(final Object object,Promise success) {

    final Settable<Throwable> exception = new Settable<Throwable>();
    final Settable<Boolean> result = new Settable<Boolean>();

    new TryCatch() {

        @Override
        protected void doTry() throws Throwable {

                Promise<Boolean> waitFor = activitiesClient.doClientWork(object);
                result.chain(waitFor);
                setState(exception, null, waitFor);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doCatch(Throwable t) throws Throwable {

            result.set(false);
            setState(exception, t, Promise.Void());
        }
    };

    handleException(object, "Failed", exception);
    return result;  
}
```

When I run my test, the control never enters tryCatch and goes straight to handleException(..) line. I am guessing I am missing something about the Settable maybe?

As suggested on other forums, I tried both approaches 'WorkflowTest' as well as 'AsyncScope' but still can't get over similar problem while writing unit test for this workflow.

Please help.

My test code looks like

```
@InjectMocks
CustomWorkflow workflow = new CustomWorkflowImpl();

@Mock
MyActivitiesClient activitiesClient;

@Test
public void testSomething() throws Throwable {

    AsyncScope scope = new AsyncScope() {

        protected void doAsync() {

        workflow.doSomething(processTransaction);
        }
    };
    scope.eventLoop();

    // assert
    verify(activitiesClient, times(1)).doClientWork(processTransaction);
}
```

However I get an exception message 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: not ready' on handleException line.

Please note I am using @InjectMocks to instantiate workflow object and I am guessing I don't need aspectweaver.jar in the classpath for this? Hope thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

Code is asynchronous so handleException is expected to be called before doTry() is executed. But if it is marked with @Asynchronous then it shouldn't be executed until exception promise is ready. Make sure that @Asynchronous is actually setup correctly.

I would also change result.set(false) to if (!result.isReady()) { result.set(false); } to ensure that it doesn't throw if it is already set.

Comment: Most probably my @Asynchronus code is setup correctly as the workflow is quite old and never had problem. Point noted for using result.isReady(), thanks. Have added more details on the original post.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not ready means that promise is not ready. if this promise is an argument of a method marked Asynchronous it is not possible if Asynchronous is working properly. Look at the stack trace if it shows synchronous call from doSomething to handleException then Asynchronous is ignored. Could it be that AspectJ configuration doesn't include the package of the unit test?